# admin page showing error in django

Tags: python, django

TypeError at /admin/student/user/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

Any idea what's it about?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import user

class userAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets=[
        (None,{'fields':['uid']}),
        (None,{'fields':['uname']}),
        (None,{'fields':['email']}),
        (None,{'fields':['password']}),
]


admin.site.register(user,userAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class user(models.Model):
    uid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    uname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.uid,self.uname

class Meta:
    db_table="user"
```

Comment: Did you defined `__unicode__` method in your model?

Comment: yes i did...!!!

Comment: Can you please show how it's defined?

Comment: don't mind the indentation...its a problem here..i've done it right in my model.

Comment: did you defined anything else for this model in admin ?

Comment: nope...........

Comment: glad its solved, just curious about the version of django you are using, i couldnt reproduce your issue with this `__unicode__` definition

Comment: version 1.8  .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__unicode__` needs to return string.

Change:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.uid,self.uname
```

into

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{} {}".format(self.uid, self.uname)
```